# I want to convert alphabets to numbers, in this way: A=0, B=1, C=2... Z=25 using php

Tags: php, string, function, numbers

I want to write a function that take input as a string and convert alphabets to number and returns the converted numbers, in this way: A(a)=1, B(b)=2, C(c)=3... Z(z)=25 using php
thanks in advance

Comment: OK - go right ahead. BTW, z=26

Comment: No sorry , I mean if anybody help me with that

Comment: Can you include your attempt in your question?

Comment: Why is it A=0 in the question title but A=1 in the question body?

Comment: sorry its my mistake. A=1,B=2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we make everything lowercase.

Then, using the `ord` function, we get the ascii code, and then substract 'a' from it.

```
function one_char_map($chr)
{
   $chr=strtolower($chr);
   return ord($chr)-ord('a');
}
function string_map($str)
{
   return implode(array_map('one_char_map',str_split($str)));
}
echo string_map('abcD');//0123
```

Comment: If my response was helpful, please accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
function conv($alph=null){
    return (!is_null($alph)?strpos("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", $alph):"Need String");
}

echo "<br /><br />";
echo conv("a");
```

EDIT :

```
$str = "abcDefghZ";
$out = "";
for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++){
    $out .= conv(strtolower($str[$i]));
}
echo $str."<br />".$out;
```

Comment: yes its working fine for just one alphabet but i want to convert like this conv("abcDefghZ") --> output will be  1234567826

Comment: hey, it should 0123456725, remember a=0, b=1 ? :)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you trying to roll your own hash function: **DONT**.
2. If you need to accept other characters from ASCII, use PHP's ord() function.
3. Try this:

This function returns the position, and optionally accepts a base integer to shift the numbers if you need to.

```
function alpha_ord($str, $base = 0) {
  $pos = stripos(
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    $str{0}
  );
  if ($pos !== FALSE) {
    $pos += $base;
  }

  return $pos;
}

print alpha_ord('A'); // 0
print alpha_ord('Z', 1); // 26
print alpha_ord('Z'); // 25
print alpha_ord('A', 65); // 65
```